# Update Record to Quickbooks from PHP API

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I have try to update a record from my database to quickbooks by PHP API, but there is an errors comes out.

My code to update just like this, the dataService is work normally. Since i have use it for query record form quickbooks is ok.

```
$resultingObj = $dataService->Update($entities[0]);
```

---

```
Object Dump: 
object(IPPItem)#2586 (54) {   
["Name"]=>   string(20)    "Factor 46 - X7Y7d-P1"   
["Sku"]=>   string(8) "X7Y7d-P1"      
["Description"]=>   string(9) "Factor 46"   
["Active"]=>   string(4)    "true"   
["SubItem"]=>   NULL   
["ParentRef"]=>   NULL   
["Level"]=>     NULL   
["FullyQualifiedName"]=>   string(20) "Factor 46 - X7Y7d-P1"      
["Taxable"]=>   string(4) "true"   
["SalesTaxIncluded"]=>   NULL      
["PercentBased"]=>   NULL   
["UnitPrice"]=>   string(8) "11390.00"      
["RatePercent"]=>   NULL   
["Type"]=>   string(9) "Inventory"      
["PaymentMethodRef"]=>   NULL   
["UOMSetRef"]=>   NULL      
["IncomeAccountRef"]=>   array(2) {   
 ["value"]=>    string(2) "79"    
 ["name"]=>    string(23) "Sales of Product Income"   
}  
["PurchaseDesc"]=>   NULL   
["PurchaseTaxIncluded"]=>   NULL   
["PurchaseCost"]=>      string(1) "0"   
["ExpenseAccountRef"]=>   array(2) {    
 ["value"]=>    string(2) "80"    
 ["name"]=>    string(18) "Cost of Goods Sold"   
}   
["COGSAccountRef"]=>   NULL   
["AssetAccountRef"]=>   array(2) {    
 ["value"]=>    string(2) "81"    
 ["name"]=>    string(15) "Inventory Asset"   
}   
["PrefVendorRef"]=>   NULL   
["AvgCost"]=>   NULL   
["TrackQtyOnHand"]=>   string(4) "true"      
["QtyOnHand"]=>   int(0)   
["QtyOnPurchaseOrder"]=>   NULL      
["QtyOnSalesOrder"]=>   NULL   
["ReorderPoint"]=>   NULL      
["ManPartNum"]=>   NULL   
["DepositToAccountRef"]=>   NULL      
["SalesTaxCodeRef"]=>   NULL   
["PurchaseTaxCodeRef"]=>   NULL      
["InvStartDate"]=>   string(10) "2016-11-05"   
["BuildPoint"]=>      NULL   
["PrintGroupedItems"]=>   NULL   
["SpecialItem"]=>   NULL      
["SpecialItemType"]=>   NULL   
["ItemGroupDetail"]=>   NULL      
["ItemAssemblyDetail"]=>   NULL   
["AbatementRate"]=>   NULL      
["ReverseChargeRate"]=>   NULL   
["ServiceType"]=>   NULL      
["ItemCategoryType"]=>   NULL   
["ItemEx"]=>   NULL   
["Id"]=>      string(2) "19"   
["SyncToken"]=>   string(1) "0"   
["MetaData"]=>      object(IPPModificationMetaData)#2569 (6) {    
 ["CreatedByRef"]=>    NULL    
 ["CreateTime"]=>    string(25) "2017-06-22T10:25:37-07:00"    
 ["LastModifiedByRef"]=>    NULL    
 ["LastUpdatedTime"]=>    string(25) "2017-06-22T10:25:37-07:00"    
 ["LastChangedInQB"]=>    NULL    
 ["Synchronized"]=>    NULL   
}   
["CustomField"]=>   NULL   
["AttachableRef"]=>   NULL   
["domain"]=>   NULL   
["status"]=>   NULL   
["sparse"]=>   NULL 
}

Exception Call Stack (Class 79 does not exist):

In     (/data/app/frameworks/yii2/vendor/intuit/QuickBooks/v3-php-sdk-2.4.1/XSD2PHP/src/com/mikebevz/xsd2php/Php2Xml.php)    on 257 getXmlFromObj()     
XmlObjectSerializer.php:68 getPostXmlFromArbitraryEntity()
XmlObjectSerializer.php:175 Serialize()
DataService.php:447 executeObjectSerializer()
DataService.php:189 Update()
QuickBooksApi.php:347 syncProduct()
QuickBooksController.php:191 actionSyncProduct() :
call_user_func_array()
    InlineAction.php:55     runWithParams()
    Controller.php:154  runAction()
    Module.php:454  runAction()
    Application.php:100     handleRequest()
    Application.php:375     run()
    index.php:20
```

I also try change my object to `JSON` and test in their API Explorer, it can update successfully. 
What is my problem on my code?

Comment: Is this some kind of the so called whitespace hell?

Answer (score 0):

That is an error in your IPPItem due to malformed object. You are using v3-php-sdk-2.4.1, which is really old. The latest version has provided a better way to do it:

```
$ItemObj = Item::update($oldItemObj, [
   "Name" => "Rock Fountain",
   "Description" => "New, updated description for Rock Fountain",
   "Active" => true,
   "FullyQualifiedName" => "Rock Fountain",
   "Taxable" => true,
   "UnitPrice" => 275,
   "Type" => "Inventory",
   "IncomeAccountRef" => [
       "value" => "79",
       "name" => "Sales of Product Income"
   ],
   "PurchaseDesc" => "Rock Fountain",
   "PurchaseCost" => 125,
   "ExpenseAccountRef" => [
       "value" => "80",
       "name" => "Cost of Goods Sold"
   ],
   "AssetAccountRef": [
       "value" => "81",
       "name" => "Inventory Asset"
   ],
   "Id" => "5",
   "SyncToken" => "2"
]);
```

Take a look at our Github for v3.2.6 php sdk now: https://github.com/intuit/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK

It should help you fix the issue.

Thanks
hao